# Get list of files for dropbox shared link

Tags: javascript, python, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

What I'm trying to do seems rather simple, but I can't find a way to do it.

Imagine somebody sends you a link for a dropbox folder. You can go to that URL and see all the files in the folder.

I'm trying to write a script in either python, php, or javascript to get all the download links in that folder from that URL.

How would I do that? Without logging in/authenticating into the account of the user who sent the link in the first place.

Comment: You want to find the contents of someone's DropBox account without authentication? Good luck with that.

Comment: but the link is shared. anyone with the link can access the contents.

Comment: Oh, now I see. In that case, look into the use of PHP's `file_get_contents()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the contents of the folder are indeed public as you've indicated in the comments, you might want to look into the use of PHP's [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function.

From the docs:

> `file_get_contents` — Reads entire file into a string

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it's possbile to do without auth. As mentioned in [Dropbox API doc](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api) — "Dropbox uses OAuth to authenticate all API requests."

Comment: Well, I didn't want to use the API but if there is no other way its fine. I can authorize the user. However, how would I get the contents of the folder (the one the link points to) with the API?